# numpy contour plot with cost function

Tags: python, numpy, contour

```
a = np.array(x)
b = np.array(y)

a_transpose = a.transpose()
a_trans_times_a = np.dot(a_transpose,a)
a_trans_times_b = np.dot(a_transpose,b)

def cost(theta):

    x_times_theta = np.dot(a, theta) 
    _y_minus_x_theta = b - x_times_theta
    _y_minus_x_theta_transpose = _y_minus_x_theta.transpose()
    return np.dot(_y_minus_x_theta_transpose, _y_minus_x_theta)


n = 256
p = np.linspace(-100,100, n)
q= np.linspace(-100,100, n)
P, Q = np.meshgrid(p,q)
pl.contourf(P, Q, cost(np.array([P,Q])) ,8, alpha =0.75, cmap = 'jet')
C = pl.contour(P,Q, cost(np.array([P,Q])), 8, colors = 'black', linewidth = 0.5 )
```

Hi, I'm trying to make a contour plot using a cost function on two parameters, involving matrix multiplication. I've tested the cost function and it works properly in interactive session. However, running it on a linspace makes it get error "ValueError: objects are not aligned". I understand now that it has to do with how I structure P,Q. Would the solution involve writing a for loop to explicitly get an array of outputs? How would I write this?

EDIT: a,b are matrices with correct size. The cost function takes a 2-vector and outputs a number.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `np.dot(a,np.array([P,Q]))` to be. I assume that this is your first problem. Also, please provide a reproducible example. I.e., what are `x` and `y`?.

Comment: Cost is calculating (b-a*theta)^T* (b - a*theta), essentially the norm squared of a 30x1 matrix. The problem seems to be that I can't just put in [P,Q] into the input, unlike doing P^2, Q^2, for example, which squares all entries inside those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly without having at hand the shapes of a and b, but this error is probably caused by `np.array[P,Q]` being a 3-dimensional array. It seems you expect it to be 2-dimensional and for `np.dot(a,theta)` to perform matrix multiplication.

Presumably you want `theta` to be the the angular coordinate at a particular x and y value. In this case you should do

```
theta = np.arctan2(Q,P)  #this is a 2D array of theta coordinates
costarray = cost(theta)  
pl.contourf(P,Q,costarray,8,alpha=0.75,cmap='jet')
```